# Jacobi iteration for finite difference: when to stop?

Tags: finite-difference, iterative-method, c, poisson

I implemented a finite difference scheme to solve Poisson's equation in a 2D grid in C. I solve the system by using Jacobi iteration. Everything works fine until I use a while loop to check whether it is time to stop iterating or not (with for loops is easy). On the notes I am following there is written that I have to compute the following:

$$\delta = max ||uNew - u||,$$

for $1 <= i,j <= n$. With $uNew$ being the current solution and $u$ the previous iteration. Obviously they are 2D arrays.

I tried to do the following:

```
// Iterations
    double delta=(tau+1), temp_delta;
    #ifdef _OPENMP
            wt1=omp_get_wtime();
    #endif
    do {

            for(i=1;i<y-1;i++) {
                    for(j=1;j<x-1;j++) {
                            uNew[i*x+j] = 0.25 * (u[(i-1)*x+j] + u[i*x+(j+1)] + u[i*x+(j-1)] + u[(i+1)*x+j] - dx*dy*func(i,j,dx,dy));
                    }
            }

            // Boundary conditions using g(x,y)
            for(j=0;j<x;j++) {
                    uNew[j] = gunc(0,j,dx,dy);
                    uNew[(y-1)*x+j] = gunc(y-1,j,dx,dy);
            }
            for(i=0;i<y;i++) {
                    uNew[i*x] = gunc(i,0,dx,dy);
                    uNew[i*x+(x-1)] = gunc(i,x-1,dx,dy);
            }

            // Check if to terminate Jacobi iteration
            for(i=1;i<y-1;i++) {
                    for(j=1;j<x-1;j++) {
                            temp_delta = abs(uNew[i*x+j]-u[i*x+j]);
                            printf("%f ", temp_delta);
                            if (delta <= temp_delta) {
                                    delta = temp_delta;
                            }
                    }
            }

            // Update solution
            for(i=0;i<y;i++) {
                    for(j=0;j<x;j++) {
                            u[i*x+j] = uNew[i*x+j];
                    }
            }
    } while(delta > tau);
```

where $\tau$ is the tolerance, $\delta$ is the result of the above formula, $temp\_delta$ is used to find the maximum and $uNew$ and $u$ are just the matrices containing the solutions at the grid points. The problem is that it's not working. Can somebody give me a hint, please?

Comment: What does the output of your printf statement say, compared to tau? And what is not working? Convergence or something else?

Comment: @Bort It stops but at the wrong iteration since the solution is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

For solving systems you shouldn't be comparing the results between each iteration  but rather computing the residual.

If you consider the matrix representation to be in the standard form:

$ A\cdot y = b $

Then you can define the residual at some iteration ($y_{i}$)

$ r =b -  A\cdot y_i  $

Then you 'just' need to determine a stopping method based on the residual vector, some choices are

$\delta < max(|r|)$

$\delta < sum(|r|)$

[Wikipedia article on the residual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_(numerical_analysis))

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I do not have a system in this case.

Comment: In fact, you have a system of linear algebraic equations, but you are solving it in a matrix free form. Your residual is a vector where each component is equal
u[i*x+j] - 0.25 * (u[(i-1)*x+j] + u[i*x+(j+1)] + u[i*x+(j-1)] + u[(i+1)*x+j] - dx*dy*func(i,j,dx,dy));

Comment: Another common criteria is to ensure $r_i/r_0 \lt tolerance$, where $r_i$, $r_0$ are the ith and initial residuals. This is sometimes used to estimate solutions at each time step of some time marching method.